# SQL Join returning all rows in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to get an account name from a table, but it is returning both rows in the table instead of the one that matches. Here's the table called LEDGERTRANS:

```
Account    Date           Voucher
402000  2014-01-14    CM-00011026   
554500  2014-01-14    CM-00011026
```

This is being joined to a table called LEDGERTABLE which will match up the Account based on this tables account number. So we get a voucher number, then the account number, then match that to the table to get the account name. The thing is that this is bringing back BOTH account numbers descriptions from the table. Here's the SQL

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    dbo.CUSTTABLE.NAME AS 'Customer',
    dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEACCOUNT AS 'Acct #',
    dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR.SALESID AS 'Sales Order',
    dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEDATE AS 'Date',
    dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEID AS 'Invoice',
    (INVOICEAMOUNT - SALESBALANCE) AS 'Inv Amt',
    'Misc Charge' AS ITEMID,
    'Misc. Charge' AS 'Reason',
    [DESCRIPTION] AS 'Division',
    CREATEDBY
    ,LEDGERTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM as 'Account Number'
FROM
    dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR INNER JOIN
    dbo.CUSTINVOICETRANS ON dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEID = dbo.CUSTINVOICETRANS.INVOICEID INNER JOIN 
    dbo.CUSTTABLE ON ACCOUNTNUM = dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEACCOUNT INNER JOIN 
    dbo.DIMENSIONS ON NUM = dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR.DIMENSION2_
    JOIN LEDGERTRANS ON LEDGERTRANS.VOUCHER = CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEID
    inner JOIN LedgerTable ON LedgerTable.ACCOUNTNUM = Ledgertrans.ACCOUNTNUM
WHERE
    dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEID LIKE 'CM-00%'
    AND
    dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEDATE BETWEEN @start AND @end
    AND
    dbo.CUSTINVOICEJOUR.DIMENSION2_ IN (@division)
    AND
    INVOICEAMOUNT <> SALESBALANCE
    AND
    CREATEDBY IN (@createdBy)
    AND 
    LEDGERTRANS.CREDITING='0'
```

This effectively brings back 2 entries for each item. How can I get rid of this extra row?

```
C3 Ingenuity    110051  SO-00670938 CM-00011026 -33.750000000000    Misc Charge 402000
C3 Ingenuity    110051  SO-00670938 CM-00011026 -33.750000000000    Misc Charge 554500
```

even:

```
Select LEDGERTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM from LedgerTable JOIN Ledgertrans ON LedgerTable.ACCOUNTNUM = Ledgertrans.ACCOUNTNUM Where LEDGERTRANS.VOUCHER = CUSTINVOICEJOUR.INVOICEID
```

Returns both results

Comment: This isn't a problem with SQL or the way JOINs work, but a problem with your query, the data, and your expectations.  Without setting up a SQL Fiddle for us to play with, only you can solve your problem.  See @StanislavL min/max suggestion for a hint.  BTW, which Misc Charge do you want?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the last column (LEDGERTABLE.ACCOUNTNUM if I understand correctly).

You can exclude the table/column from the query, or GROUP BY the rest of columns leaving MIN/MAX from the exisitng account numbers